# How to unzip files into the current directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory, zip

I am trying to write a bash script that will automatically unzip mp3 downloads and move them into my `~/music` folder.

My problem is that when I use the unzip command, it creates it's own folder within the downloads folder, when I would rather it to just list all the mp3 files in the `~/downloads` folder.

My question is if there is a way to have the files listed in the `~/downloads` folder instead of creating its own folder within the downloads directory, OR if there is a way to automatically change directories to the resulting unzipped folder assuming I don't know the name of that folder?

Sorry if that sounds confusing, but thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`unzip -j`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/unzip.1.html) ("junk paths") option, which will extract just the files without recreating the subdirectories.